# Action Bar Compatibly issue with API level 8

Tags: android

I have used action bar in my activity.When i run app on emulator which has android 4.2 version it is working fine.but when i run app on my real mobile which has android 2.3.5 version when app reached on that activity which has action bar it is crashing

Comment: @MadScientist Yes there is. ActionBar isn't supported on API 8. That's the problem. OP You really should read the documentation first. Search for ActionBarSherlock if you need to support prior to API 11.

Answer (score 2):

You should use ActionBarSherlock if you want an action bar that is compatible with all api versions of android. You should also be using the support libraries

Check this out for more info on ABS http://actionbarsherlock.com/

It is well maintained, open source and highly recommended by most Android Developers and it even gets a mention in one of the Google I/O seminars (can't remember which off the top of my head)

**UPDATE** - Google I/O seminar regarding navigation https://developers.google.com/live/shows/5698617/ Well worth watching

Comment: I fired up a `2.3.3` emulator and I don't see an action bar.  I had been testing on my `4.2` phone.  Any thoughts why?  Are the ADB themes compatible as well?

Comment: @mattblang Nope! Themes must descend from a Holo theme. So long as you have followed the ABS documentation on how to integrate, it will work fine. Works for me on 2.2 and up to latest 4.2

Answer (score 0):

Action bar started after ver 11 so you will need to add support library in order to use it in an older ver :

1- Download this library(Sharlok Action Bar)

http://actionbarsherlock.com/

2- and use getSupportActionBar instead of get action bar in your class that crashes

Comment: thanks for everyone's support.Kindly can you tell me briefly how to use this library in my my project.please tell me everything step by step

Comment: here you can find what you want from A to Z .. 
http://androidfragments.blogspot.com/2011/10/how-to-use-actionbar-sherlock.html